# Run a webpage when dropbox file is uploaded

Tags: asp-classic, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm the IT person of a mortgage company.
I've programmed a CRM system in ASP (VB) that holds all the data for each client and staff comments.
Each incoming fax document from our clients is uploaded to DropBox so it can be backed up and shared with all our employees.

I want to automatically add a comment in the client's data page whenever I upload a new file to that client's DropBox folder. Folder and client names are the same...

basically:

```
if dropbox-new-file then run-webpage addfilecomment.asp?Client=DropBoxFolderName&FileName=Filename...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Which part of the code do you need help with? Detecting when a new dropbox file is uploaded, or running the webpage?

Comment: I need help with how to trigger the page when dropbox recieves a new file, and I should know the dropbox folder name when the page triggers, so I know which client to add the comment to...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I SEEM TO HAVE FOUND A WAY !

Abit of a detour but...

1) I use IF THIS THEN THAT engine to send me an email with file name in subject when a new file is uploaded to dropbox.

2) The recieved subject is being processed with Tasker (for android) to run a page with variable names as I wanted.

I'll polish this during next week, but what I basically get is exactly what I wanted - when file is uploaded to dropbox, a page with variables runs and writes it in my CRM system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but with using 3rd party tools, for example you could use "wget for windows"
http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm